# reset values before running next mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, graphql

I am running a graphql query inside `getFriendId()`that returns an id, followed by a mutation (inside `addFriend()`, which uses the id, along with an input (email) that the user types in. The problem is that on the first attempt, the mutation works fine and with correct values. However, when I change the email address on the input and run the query/mutation again, the values from my previous attempt are being used.

For instance, in the second attempt, the mutation is still using the id that we got in the first attempt. So basically, the values with `setId` and setEmail aren't being updated timely. How can I fix this?

```
const [id, setId] = useState('');
const [friendEmail, setFriendEmail] = useState('');

const [loadUsers, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery);
const [createUserRelationMutation, { data: addingFriendData, loading: addingFriendLoading, error: addingFriendError }] = useCreateUserRelationMutation();

const getFriendId = () => {
    console.log('Email', friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase());
    loadUsers({
      variables: {
        where: { email: friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase() },
      },
    });
    if (data) {     
        console.log('ID', data.users.nodes[0].id);
        setId(data.users.nodes[0].id);      
    } 
    addFriend();
  };

  const addFriend = () => {
    console.log('Whats the Id', Number(id));
       createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
               input: {relatedUserId: Number(id), type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 }
            },
       });
       if (addingFriendData){
         console.log('Checking')
         console.log(data);
       }
       if(addingFriendError){
         console.log('errorFriend', addingFriendError.message);
         setErrorMessage(addingFriendError.message);
       }
  }


const handleSubmit = () =>
    {getFriendId();};
```

The return looks like something like this:

```
<Input
                  placeholder="Email"
                   onChangeText={(text) => setFriendEmail(text)}
                  value={friendEmail}
                />

<Button
                  rounded
                  onPress={() => handleSubmit()}>
                    Add Friend{' '}
                </Button>
```

Current Picture Of My Code:

```
export const AddFriendEmailPage: React.FunctionComponent<AddFriendEmailPageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showAddFriendEmailPage,
}) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState('');
  const [friendEmail, setFriendEmail] = useState('ana@hotmail.com');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [loadUsers, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery, {
    variables: {
      where: { email: friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase() },
    },
    onCompleted: ( data: any ) => {
      console.log('Working');
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          console.log('No user');
          setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
        } else {
          const friendId = data.users.nodes[0].id; 
          console.log('friendId', friendId);
          // setId(data.users.nodes[0].id);

          const relationParams = {
            input: {
              relatedUserId: Number( friendId ),
              type: RelationType.Friend,
              userId: 8, // current user?
            },
          }                             
          console.log("relation params", relationParams);

          // fire second query/mutation using received data
          createUserRelationMutation( { variables: relationParams } );

        }
      } else {
        if (error) {
          setErrorMessage(error.message);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
    },
  ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation( {
    variables: {
      input: {
        relatedUserId: Number(id),
        type: RelationType.Friend,
        userId: 8,
      },
    },
    onCompleted: ( addingFriendData: any) => {
      console.log("relation created", addingFriendData);
    }
  });

  return (
            <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchTopTextContainer}>
            </View>
            <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchFieldContainer}>
              <Item style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.searchField}>
                <Input
                  placeholder="Email"
                  //onChangeText={(text) => setFriendEmail(text)}
                  value={friendEmail}
                />
              </Item>
              <View style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button
                  rounded
                  style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.button}
                  //onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
                  onPress={()=>loadUsers()}
                  >
                  <Text style={scaledAddFriendEmailStyles.text}>
                    Add Friend{' '}
                  </Text>
                </Button>
              </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is `useCreateUserRelationMutation` coming from. Is it a custom hook. If so, can you show it please

Answer (score 4):

Both (mutation and lazyquery) have possibility to define `onCompleted` (inside options object) function for handling responses/results.

`if(data)` doesn't wait for results - `data` is from component scope, will be defined after first `useLazyQuery` firing.

`onCompleted` handler receives `data` as argument, it will be current request result (different to `data` in component scope - later, in next render 'flow' will be the same).

### update

```
 const [loadUsers, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery, {
    variables: {
      where: { email: friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase() },
    },
    onCompleted: ( data ) => {
      // getFriendId
      console.log('Working');
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          console.log('No user');
          setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
        } else {
          const friendId = data.users.nodes[0].id; 
          console.log('friendId', friendId);
          // needed?
          // setId(data.users.nodes[0].id);

          const relationParams = {
            input: {
              relatedUserId: Number( friendId ),
              type: RelationType.Friend,
              userId: 5, // current user?
            },
          }                             
          console.log("relation params", relationParams);

          // fire second query/mutation using received data
          createUserRelationMutation( { variables: relationParams } );

        }
      } else {
        if (error) {
          setErrorMessage(error.message);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
    },
  ] = useMutation(CreateUserRelationMutation, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        relatedUserId: Number(id),
        type: RelationType.Friend,
        userId: 5,
      },
    },
    onCompleted: ( data ) => {
      console.log("relation created", data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212995/discussion-on-answer-by-xadm-reset-values-before-running-next-mutation).